# pytorch-lightning example throws assertion error

Tags: pytorch-lightning

I'm using the following code out of the box from this url: https://lightning-transformers.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tasks/nlp/question_answering.html

```
import pytorch_lightning as pl
from transformers import AutoTokenizer

from lightning_transformers.task.nlp.question_answering import (
    QuestionAnsweringTransformer,
    SquadDataModule,
)

tokenizer = AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained(pretrained_model_name_or_path="bert-base-uncased")
model = QuestionAnsweringTransformer(pretrained_model_name_or_path="bert-base-uncased")
dm = SquadDataModule(
    batch_size=1,
    dataset_config_name="plain_text",
    max_length=384,
    version_2_with_negative=False,
    null_score_diff_threshold=0.0,
    doc_stride=128,
    n_best_size=20,
    max_answer_length=30,
    tokenizer=tokenizer,
)
trainer = pl.Trainer(accelerator="auto", devices="auto", max_epochs=1)

trainer.fit(model, dm)
```

which throws this error

```
AssertionError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-2-0b608c02a52e> in <module>
     14 trainer = pl.Trainer(accelerator="auto", devices="auto", max_epochs=1)
     15 
---> 16 trainer.fit(model, dm)

16 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/lightning_transformers/task/nlp/question_answering/datasets/squad/processing.py in postprocess_qa_predictions(examples, features, predictions, version_2_with_negative, n_best_size, max_answer_length, null_score_diff_threshold, output_dir, prefix)
    245     all_start_logits, all_end_logits, example_ids = predictions
    246 
--> 247     assert len(predictions[0]) == len(features), f"Got {len(predictions[0])} predictions and {len(features)} features."
    248 
    249     # Build a map example to its corresponding features.

AssertionError: Got 2 predictions and 10784 features.
```

I was simply trying to get a single example from the documentation to run within google colab before investigating further if this would meet my use case, but I see an error when I try to use the example as is, which is disheartening to consider investigating it.  Nothing comes up when I google "AssertionError: Got 2 predictions and 10784 features."

Comment: Do you still have this problem? I have a nearly identical problem (the only difference being that I modified mine to use a local dataset I made), and I can't figure it out either. The only thing I've figured out is that the error goes away when you set the batch size to 5392, but then I run out of GPU memory. :/